# Missing Cookies using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, cookies, www-mechanize

I am using WWW::Mechanize to crawl a website and collect information on the Cookies being set.    Here is the code I'm using:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar, autocheck => 1 );

my $response = $mech->get('http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png');

print "Cookie:\n" . $cookie_jar->as_string;
```

When I use Chrome and check the resources, I can see a cookie getting set.  However, when I run my code I get nothing.  Been having this issue on a number of websites.  Why am I missing cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (prints cookies) for http://google.com/

I have used firefox to visit http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png. No cookies have been set.

Comment: When I visit with Firefox or Chrome, I get 5 cookies:  __utma, __utmv, __utmz, _pinterest_sess, csrftoken.  Why don't any of these show in the WWW::Mechanize cookie jar?

Comment: Have you visited other pages at the site before downloading the image?